# touchstart event listener returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Code:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    var Ypos = e.screenY;
    console.log(Ypos);
});
```

Ypos returns undefined in the console. I have chekced previous answers but cannot find a solution. Why is Ypos returning udefined and not the y-coordinates of the mouse?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `screenY` is a property of a [`Touch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch) object, not [`TouchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) object. `Touch` object can be obtained from one of `TouchEvent` properties (e.g. `TouchEvent.touches`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single finger touch, you need to retrieve the touch object with `e.touches[0]`.

`e.touches` (or `e.changedTouches`, `e.targetTouches`) is an array, because this spec supports multiple finger touch as well.

Once you get the object, you could use either `screenX/Y`, `pageX/Y`, or `clientX/Y`, which are defined in the [**spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#idl-def-Touch). However, browser implementations may still vary.

Comment: thanks, I should have realised it can handle more than one touch. And thanks again